# itext correctly get each image position within page or document

Tags: matrix, itext

Experimenting with itext I am extracting both text and images from pdf files. For my purpose I build an html file using the text and images. The goal is to place the extracted images throughout the text rather than placing them at the end as I do currently.

After some research itext renderInfo.getImageCTM() appears to be just what I need, however the coordinates returned do not resemble the positions of some of the images when comparing to what's being displayed in adobe reader.

My MyImageRenderListener class has this

```
Matrix matrix = renderInfo.getImageCTM();
float x = matrix.get(Matrix.I31);
float y = matrix.get(Matrix.I32);
```

Which should give me the XY, top left hand corner position of each image, if I've understood it correctly.

Here is the [pdf file](http://www.partyplan.org/canopus/mossy.pdf) I will be referring to

It's a 4 page PDF that contains either one or two images per page.

```
PAGE       X        Y
Page1      33.0     358.5

Page2 1st  321.7    419.9  
Page2 2nd  41.2     182    

Page3 1st  43.1     307.5  
Page3 2nd  417      58.5   

Page4      292.5    457.5
```

When comparing the coordinates output to the actual document the numbers do not seem to make sense. For example, On page3, the second image Y (58.5) is lower than the first image Y (307.5) on the same page. That would put image 2 on page 3 before image 1??

Also none of the Y and some of the X coordinates appear to be correct when comparing to the layout in any reader.

What am I getting wrong or miss understanding please?

Comment: To start with, PDF coordinate systems usually have the origin in the **lower** left, not the upper left as you assume. And you will usually get the coordinates of the lower left corner of the image, not the top left.

Comment: thanks mkl, didnt know that, but still doesn't make the coords on page 2 and 3 make sense?

Comment: Of course they do. 0,0 is in the lower left. Thus, images further up the page have a higher y coordinate.

Comment: Ahh - the penny's just dropped. Thanks