# Adding attachment links between lines in itext for pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to use itext to create pdf files from existing files (DXL --> Domino XML) which can have attachments and when that happens the attachments need to be imported to the new pdf with an annotation link on the same place it was on the prior file.

With annotation link I mean a symbol to doubleclick and then open the attached file (e.g. Adobe standard is a pushpin)

So far I managed to create a pdf file and attach such a annotation link but I placed it by using the trial and error method (change x,y and then test again also with a hardcoded text to test it).

When there are about 3 linespaces it means, that there was at least one attachment and they need to be put there again.
Unfortunately I can't post any pictures of how my pdfs look because I have no rep --> new user :/

Now my question is how can I find these "empty lines" to add annotation links there and if there are more than one how can I insert them one to another and not all on one point?

________________Edit_____________________

```html
public void createPdf(String filename) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        List list = new List(List.UNORDERED);

        Paragraph pa1 = new Paragraph();
        pa1.add(
            "This is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some              textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is                some textThis is some textThis is some text\n");

        Paragraph pa2 = new Paragraph();
        pa2.add("This is some textThis is some textThis is some Text\n");

        list.add("This is a list elementThis is a list element\n");

        list.add("This is a list elementThis is a list element\n");

        Paragraph pa3 = new Paragraph();
        pa5.add("This is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some text.\n");

        Paragraph pa4 = new Paragraph();
        pa6.add(
            "This is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some              textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some text\n");

        Paragraph pa5 = new Paragraph();
        pa7.add(
            "This is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some              textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some textThis is some text \n");

        document.open();
        document.add(pa1);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.add(pa2);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.add(list);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.add(pa3);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.add(pa4);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.add(pa5);
        document.close();
}
```

Best Regards
Christoph

Comment: There is no such thing as "empty lines" in a PDF. Text is added at absolute coordinates and depending on the distance between the coordinates of two lines, you perceive one or more empty lines. You see them with your human mind. A machine doesn't see lines. It only sees a gap, a distance between two coordinates. You may be able to solve your problem using page event (e.g. using `onGenericTag()`), but your question isn't complete: we don't know how you are introducing the *empty lines* you are talking about.

Comment: @Bruno thank you for your comment. By now these "empty lines" are added to a document with `document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);` but the text I use is just hardcoded to some paragraphs, that I can see how it would look like. If I understood that write i could use `onGenericTag()` to ask if there was a `Chunk.NEWLINE` or is it used differently? I'll also edit my code for the pdf creation into the question, hope this might help.

Comment: With `onGenericTag()`, you'd create a *special* `Chunk` object. For instance: an empty `Chunk` that adds a file attachment annotation instead of content. Please download the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) and take a look at the chapter about page events for some examples.

Comment: @Bruno Thank you for your help, I've read the book and it's very interesting but there was a change in the requirement and now I get the file prepared with a picture where an annotation attachment is to set. I've already seen that there's a way with Matrix from the ImageRenderListener to get the coordinates from the image and give them to the annotation rectangle. This is what I mean: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426345/itext-correctly-get-each-image-position-within-page-or-document)

Comment: Yes, if you have images, that's the way to go. It's also in the bok: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055187/get-co-ordinates-of-image-in-pdf